# If statement does not printing any output while checking reponses from requests

Tags: python

I have created for loop for checking if any of the endpoints return 200 code on a website

where *urilist* is list which contains the endpoints

```
for uris in uriList:

    req = requests.get(uris, timeout=10)
    successSTR = 'Detected Swagger UI at {}'.format(uris)
    if req.status_code == 200 | req.status_code == 301 | req.status_code == 304:
          print(successSTR)
```

I tried to print the status code and got 200 responses but my string was not printed

Comment: I think you meant to use `or` instead of `|`.

Comment: Even better: `if req.status_code in [200,301,304]:`